# Access MacBook Pro remotely while in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

Is it possible to access a MacBook Pro remotely while in sleep mode using a software such as TeamViewer?

If not, what are the other possibilities, if any, to wake up and access it?

Comment: not with Team Viewer, it has be on and running on the other computer.

Comment: Generally, the only things that can wake a computer from sleep are Wake on LAN or input from connected devices. Are there any computers on the same LAN that you are able to control remotely?

Comment: Could be. What did you have in mind with that computer on the same LAN?